# how to capture connection error in client side socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i am new to socket.io. i want to notify user when the internet connection drops
or failed to connect to the server in socket.io. in client pc if we drop the internet connection, socket.io makes xhr pooling  to connect to the server. My intention is to notify the user when ever the connection drops or server is down and client failed to connect it.

The following code is of client side socket.io app, but following events never fires when ever internet connection failed or server is down.

```
 var socket = io('http://192.168.1.109:3000');

    socket.on("private msg", function (data) {
        console.log(data.msg);

    });

    socket.on("conect_error", function (data) {
        console.log("connect)error");
        // this event never fires
    });


    socket.on("connect_timeout",function(){
       console.log("connection timeout");
       //this event never fires
    });

    socket.on("reconnect", function () {
        console.log("reconnected");
       // this works fine
    });       


    socket.on("disconnect",function(){
        console.log("disconnected");
       // this works fine
    });
```

Comment: Which version of socket.io are you using?

Comment: socket.io version 1.3.6